# What is the convention for dynamically creating an object instance?

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic

I'm creating a page that will allow you to put multiple widgets on it, and some widgets can be duplicated on the page.  So I need to understand the proper convention for creating an object instance on the fly.

```
// my bulb object
var bulb = {
    state: 0
};

// programatically, hard-coded instance name of 'bulb1'
var bulb1 = new bulb();

$('button').click(function() {
    // create another new bulb instance here with dynamic name
});
```

Or am I just going down the wrong path all together?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, we use functions (so called constructor functions) to instantiate object instances.

```
function Bulb() {
    this.state = 0;
}

// one instance
var bulb1 = new Bulb();

// another instance
var bulb2 = new Bulb();
```

---

Your code doesn't work because your `bulb` is a regular object and not a function, so you cannot call it (which you are trying to do with `bulb()`).

---

**Update:** You could store your instances into an Array global variable:

```
var bulbs = [];
```

And then, whenever you create a new instance, just just make sure that you put it in the Array.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var bulb = new Bulb();

    // do stuff with bulb

    // make sure to store it into the Array
    bulbs.push(bulb);
});
```

You can access the instances at any time like so:

```
bulbs[0] // the 1. instance
bulbs[1] // the 2. instance
// etc.
```

Comment: Yes, I should have tested before posting.  My issue, though, still remains.  I need dynamically instantiated objects.  What is the convention for naming, or referring to them?

Comment: @Shawn In my answer above, `bulb1` and `bulb2` are instantiated objects. You can put `var bulb3 = new Bulb()` inside your click handler to make it dynamical. The naming convention is: 1. the constructor function should be upper-cased (like Dog, Person, School, etc.), 2. object instances should be lower-cased.

Comment: I'm concerned about what to do when you click the button more than once in order to create another object instance.

Comment: Sime, thanks so much for continuing to explain.  I'm just concerned that when you do 'var bulb = new Bub()' again, wouldn't that overwrite the previous 'bulb' instance?

Comment: @Shawn No. Each time the click event occurs, the function will be called again. Every time a function is called, a new scope (namespace) is created for that function call. Once the function call returns, all local variables are destroyed.