# Dynamically create an instance of an object

Tags: javascript, json, oop

I am trying to create a simple interface for generating data in a JSON format.  The first object can be added successfully.  But when I try to add another one (appending it to the "myDict" array object: see code below), the values of the original object are overwritten, and I seem to be getting an empty key/value pair added, also.

I'm guessing that this is related to not creating a new instance of the "createObj" object each time a new one is added to "myDict".  So, I'm trying to find out how to create new instances dynamically.  Here's my code so far:

```
// VARIABLES
var myDict = [];

// CLASSES
function createObj() {
    this.myObj = {};
}
createObj.prototype.newPair = function() {
    this.newKey = document.getElementById('key').value;
    this.newValue = document.getElementById('value').value;
    this.myObj[this.newKey] = this.newValue;

    console.log(this.myObj);

    document.getElementById('key').value = null;
    document.getElementById('value').value = null;
    document.getElementById('key').focus();
}
createObj.prototype.addIt = function() {
    myDict.push(this.myObj);
    console.log(myDict);
}

// ACTIONS
$('#createNew').click(function() {
    $('#item').show();
    var myItem = new createObj();

    $('button#create').click(function() {
        myItem.newPair();
    });

    $('#done').click(function() {
        $('#item').hide();
        myItem.addIt();
    });
});
```

I have reviewed a similar Stack Overflow question here: [What is the convention for dynamically creating an object instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973405/what-is-the-convention-for-dynamically-creating-an-object-instance)

. . . but it doesn't seem to offer any answers to my problem.  If it's helpful, here's the JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/mysterexs/rffmV/

Note: the JSFiddle doesn't show the output, but it gives you all the code and offers more context.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know very little about JQuery, but your problem seems to be that you add a new event handler each time(in the first event handle), and it adds extra property to `myItem`(because of the closure the function still has access to it), and extra object to the array(same reason).
Do something like this:

```
var myItem;
// ACTIONS
$('#createNew').click(function () {
    $('#item').show();
    myItem = new createObj();

});
$('button#add').click(function () {  
        myItem.newPair();
    });
$('#done').click(function () {
        $('#item').hide();
        myItem.addIt();
    });
```

I used a global variable like to make it easy, you could find some better solutions.

Comment: Thanks so much grape_mao.  This did the trick.  I definitely need to look into closures more and better understand them.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is intriguing because, on one hand, you create a class, define prototypical properties within the class, and instantiate a class. On the other hand, only one instance of the class is present at any one time, rendering the class unnecessary. There are also strange behaviours directly detectable by inspection that you are simultaneously creating a series of textboxes and destroying them, which means their values will always remain in one location.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wb5Xj/) is a fiddle that solves these problems, bearing in mind that the HTML markup has changed to make sure IDs are not duplicated on the same page.

```
// VARIABLES
var myDict = [];

// CLASSES
function createObj() {
    this.myObj = $('.item').eq(0);
}
createObj.prototype.newPair = function () {
    var newPair = this.myObj.clone();
    $('#container').append(newPair);
    newPair.find('.key').focus();
}
createObj.prototype.addIt = function () {
    myDict = [];
    $('.item').each(function (i, o) {
        var item = $(o);
        myDict.push({
            'key': item.find('.key').val(),
            'value': item.find('.value').val()
        });
    });
    console.log(myDict);
}

// ACTIONS
var myItem = new createObj();
$('.item').hide();

$('#createNew').click(function () {
    $('.item').show();
});
$('#add').click(function () {
    myItem.newPair();
});

$('#done').click(function () {
    $('.item').hide();
    myItem.addIt();
});
```